# python sshtunnel: I get the following error: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I'm new to python. I'm trying to connect to mysql using python. This is the code below:

```
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel

with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ssh_username="ravi",
    ssh_address="maxim.com",
    ssh_pkey="~/.ssh/id_rsa_host",
    remote_bind_address=("127.0.0.1", 3306),
) as tunnel:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        user="power_pack",
        password="987654",
        host="db.maxim.com",
        port=3306,
    )
```

And I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ashok/Documents/Repos/db-migration/src/index.py", line 4, in <module>
    with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
  File "/Users/ashok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 966, in __init__
    (self.ssh_password, self.ssh_pkeys) = self._consolidate_auth(
  File "/Users/ashok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1148, in _consolidate_auth
    ssh_loaded_pkeys = SSHTunnelForwarder.get_keys(
  File "/Users/ashok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1105, in get_keys
    ssh_pkey = SSHTunnelForwarder.read_private_key_file(
  File "/Users/ashok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1304, in read_private_key_file
    ssh_pkey = pkey_class.from_private_key_file(
  File "/Users/ashok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 235, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "/Users/ashok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 55, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/Users/ashok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 175, in _from_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key_file("RSA", filename, password)
  File "/Users/ashok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 308, in _read_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key(tag, f, password)
  File "/Users/ashok/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 316, in _read_private_key
    m = self.BEGIN_TAG.match(lines[start])
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Also passing key to paramiko parses the file correctly,

```
paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("~/.ssh/id_rsa_host")
```

Comment: It looks like your private key file is empty or otherwise incomplete because the error comes from when the `paramiko` package tries to read the key. Can you use the same file to start a SSH session in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in terminal

Comment: Also using Paramiko file private key is parsed correctly. But when I pass it through the ssh tunnel it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the response.

- It seems this an issue with Paramiko. Paramiko code loops through
  various types of SSH keys. And apparently throws an error if the
  first key type doesnt match.
- And there is a PR added to fix this bug but its still not merged. I
  made the change locally to get this working.